# @Mock MessageSource always returns null for getMessage in Junit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have the following at the top of my test class:

`@Mock 
private MessageSource messageSource`

Through debugging, I can confirm the messageSource attribute is getting mocked and is not null.
The test case eventually reaches this point:

```
messageSource.getMessage("DATA.IS.EMPTY", null, Locale.ENGLISH)
```

I confirmed that I have the code "DATA.IS.EMPTY" in my message properties file with the message string. I know the message properties file is configured correctly because I have seen the messages appear in the app when it is running. However, in the Junit test case, the getMessage above is returning as null. Looking at the spring documentation for MessageSource, getMessage should either return the message string or a NoSuchMessageException, never null. Is it expected to get a null for getMessage in a Junit test case because MessageSource is being mocked? Am I not mocking MessageSource properly? I know I can mock the getMessage method to return the message string, but that doesn't seem right to me because I thought the JUnit test case should check that the MessageSource can find the code in the message properties file.

Comment: Has `MessageSource` been injected into another target test class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but that doesn't seem right to me because I thought the JUnit test case should check that the MessageSource can find the code in the message properties file.

Seems what you really need is a real injection and not a mocked one

This

```java
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

Instead of

```java
@Mock
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a mock, it will return null.

You have to explicitly configure that mock to return something on mentioned call, but it looks to me like you want to use actual implementation, not a mock.